# Reliable notifications on iOS without using push notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, reliability

I'm looking for a way to reliably implement notifications for an iOS app without using the Apple push notification service.

Due to some constraints on the app - it's not a centralized app, the company sells server software to customers who run on their own servers, from which they don't want to share any information with a centralized service, and it frequently operates in closed networks that don't have internet connectivity for safety reasons or simply because they are in remote locations where internet traffic is expensive and not used unless absolutely necessary - I can't use the standard push notification route.

I've implemented a system that uses the iOS background fetch mechanism, performing a background download that creates a local notification if needed, upon completion of the download - and it works, sort-of, partially. But since background fetch is initiated at the discretion of some magical iOS algorithm, it's quite unreliable. At best it manages to get a single notification after the user minimizes the application, or sometimes iOS does not call application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler at all (at least for periods of time that essentially make the feature useless) even though I've called setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval to UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum.

Is there some way to ask iOS to initiate background fetching more frequently and reliably? Is there some other method I can use to deliver notifications to iOS apps that are in the background, without relying on the availability of anything else on the network, except a server that I control? Is this a dead end?

Comment: This might be a dead end.  Push messaging actually keeps a session connected between the device and Apple's servers. Generally, an app cannot keep a network connection alive when it is not in the foreground. If the app is not for the App Store then you could possibly use the audio background mode;   Your app can "play silence" while monitoring your server for notification data.

Comment: In case this is useful to someone - I was able to work around the initial problem of not being able to keep a connection open in the background - by essentially "pretending" that the network connection is bad and / or the server is taking a long time to process the request. I don't specify a content length in the response, keep sending some whitespace once in a while, and end the contents with some valid json when I actually have something to respond with. This works, to some extent, but usually, after the first response is done, iOS does not restart the fetch process for a long time.

Comment: And, sadly, yes, in my case, I need to app to comply with App Store rules, so I can't use the background "audio player" approach, but that can be useful to people who don't serve their apps through the App Store - good hint.

Comment: Maybe you could investigate the `newsstand` background mode if it would fit your app's way of presenting some information to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the idea - somehow I had completely forgotten that such a background mode exists. But there are two problems for me: 1) In https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html it says the mode is for "The app is a Newsstand app that downloads and processes magazine or newspaper content in the background", and I'm pretty sure Apple will enforce that. 2) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/newsstandkit says that the whole process relies on APNs - if those were available, I'd use them.